# Show drop down menu when typing

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, uitextfield

I have a UITextField and I would like to create something a bit like the drop down menu in the ios contact app.

When the user starts typing, I would like the menu to drop down. It doesn't really need to limit the data it shows based on what the names but it would be great if it could (ex: it if the user types "m" it only shows strings beginning with m and so on). If the user selects one, that type would be sent to the UITextField where it would be displayed. If there is any open source picker like this, it would be great. If not, is there a way to present something like that that contains all items from the array. This would not have to be complex, it wouldn't have to limit the data shown when the user types or anything.

Comment: You just add a table and scrollview(to show any number of items) below your textfield and keep them hidden,when you start typing make them visible.This much only you have to do..

Comment: For filtering people you can use NSPredicate.If you need some guidence there are many examples for drop down.Have a look..http://code4app.net/search/drop%20down%20menu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Response based on [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/336/auto-complete-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-auto-complete-with-custom-values) link. Will show you how to get URL values in a dropdown that will autocomplete.

1. You need to have an NSMutableArray with the possible autocomplete values. In this example, we’ll use an NSMutableArray of pastURLs, and every time the user browses to a URL we’ll add it to the array.
2. You need to create a UITable to show the values

   ```
    autocompleteTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:
    CGRectMake(0, 80, 320, 120) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    autocompleteTableView.delegate = self;
    autocompleteTableView.dataSource = self;
    autocompleteTableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    autocompleteTableView.hidden = YES;  
    [self.view addSubview:autocompleteTableView];
   ```
3. You need to show the table when the field is being edited

   ```
   - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

        autocompleteTableView.hidden = NO;

        NSString *substring = [NSString stringWithString:textField.text];
        substring = [substring stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
        [self searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring:substring];
        return YES;
   }
   ```
4. And finally only show stuff in the table that is being edited

   ```
    -(void)searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring:(NSString *)substring {

        // Put anything that starts with this substring into the autocompleteUrls array

        // The items in this array is what will show up in the table view

        [autocompleteUrls removeAllObjects];

        for(NSString *curString in pastUrls)  {
             NSRange substringRange = [curString rangeOfString:substring];
             if (substringRange.location == 0) {
                  [autocompleteUrls addObject:curString]; 
             }
        }
             [autocompleteTableView reloadData];
     }
   ```

Don't forget to add the proper UITable and UITextfield delegates to your .h file.

Comment: This is a link only answer bro. You will be don voted pretty quick. I suggest you expand on it.

Comment: Did not realise that link only was frowned upon. I will put more info.

Comment: +1 for a good answer.:)

Comment: Hahah thanks. It will have to do in lieu of a checkmark :)